# Passing Command Line Arguments that contain hyphens

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I am attempting to pass command line arguments to a console application(Computer Language Compiler).

**My Problem:** The argument I am passing contains a *hyphen* character and it is causing an error "- was unexpected command/character".

This is the command line argument I am using(12d.exe is the application/compiler):

```
12d.exe "C:/Staff - Name/abc.4dm"
```

It seems that its looking at the '-' as a command and not part of a directory/string. Maybe I can use a batch file to perform this command line and reformat the directory path? You know how like in HTTP POST I can use urlencode to format post commands, maybe I can encode the command line in a batch file.

Comment: 1. off topic. 2. This is completely dependent on what is inside 12d.exe, there's nothing you can do from outside.

Comment: @bmarulies you are right it depends on 12d.exe. You are not right, as there are always things to do from the outside.

Comment: did you try printing the strings in the argv variable ? And how do you actually parse the command line ?

Comment: I have an off topic question, do you call "-" hyphen or dash when you describe "somecmd -f -p" something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that 12d.exe does not understand some valid filenames, shame on 12d.exe.

There are a couple actions you might do,

1. try to pass the **short filename** instead. It may work in some cases where the hyphen `-` is off the right of the string. Not in your case, though, as it will probably translate as `STAFF-~1` or something similar.

   ```
   call :invoke12d "Staff - Name\abc.4dm"
   goto :eof
   :invoke12d
   12d %~s1
   goto :eof
   ```
2. or create a **junction**, a symbolic link, to call the directory with another name that does not contain hyphens. See this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768 for more information and to download a simple tool.

   ```
   junction staffnam "Staff - Name"
   12d.exe "staffnam/abc.4dm"
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You could try adding a `^` to "escape" the hyphen in the batch making batch ignore it.

```
12d.exe "C:/Staff ^- Name/abc.4dm"
```